# Div position related to its container and window

Tags: html, css

I can't manage to style a div so that it is horizontally positioned at the middle (width) of its container And vertically at the middle of the window height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
body, html { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div { padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box; }

.parent {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  background: lightpink;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">middle</div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/pxsL7usy/

**Logic:**

Centering a `div` horizontally inside its parent/container is pretty easy, we just define a `width` and add `margin: 0 auto`.

To make an element in the center of viewport vertically, you can use the CSS viewport units, in this case `vh` which is viewport height. You apply a non-static `position` (like `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`) and a `top` value of `50vh` to offset the div to half of viewport. Then add `transform: translateY(-100%)` to reduce the element's height from the top offset.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible in pure css, at least not if you want decent cross browser support. You can centre horizontally with css but vertically will require some javascript.

Comment: You need to set div position to fixed. If your div have some height you should add top:0;, bottom: 0; and margin: auto;. Next step is centering horizontally. JS will help ;).
It should look like this:

var a = container.offset().left + (container.width/2);
div.css({ left: a - div.width / 2 })
I think its all :)

P.S. 
Its a pseudocode :P